# Scrambled output from script (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

I found a weird bug in one of my scripts today.
Some background first.The script runs sequentially a bunch of commands and creates an HTML template which is after that send.Right now this particular template was scrambled and I can't understand why.Here's a sample :

***//Wrong.See that the second row is cut.The string should be "Affected CI Serial Number".Also the email should start with "Dear Team" and it's not on the position it should be.***

```
Affected CI Name: <name>

cted CI Serial Number: <SN> 

Dear Team,
```

Nowhere in the script I run something in the background.Everything should run sequentially :

```
echo "<b>" Affected CI Name: "</b>" $(grep $sn $FPATH/arraylist.txt|awk '{print $2}')"<br>" >> $FPATH/mail
echo "<b>" Affected CI Serial Number: "</b>" $(grep $sn $FPATH/arraylist.txt|awk '{print $1}') "<br>" >> $FPATH/mail
```

I think that this issue won't be reproducible.My question is only how could such thing happen ? So far everything was running correctly.Am I missing something about the output redirection ? To my knowledge each command should wait for return code from the previous and then continue the next.

//Linux version

2.6.26-2-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Mar 4 21:48:06 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see if it helps :

```
execute_commands()
{
echo "<b>" Affected CI Name: "</b>" $(grep $sn $FPATH/arraylist.txt|awk '{print $2}')"<br>" 
echo "<b>" Affected CI Serial Number: "</b>" $(grep $sn $FPATH/arraylist.txt|awk '{print $1}') "<br>"
}

execute_commands >> $FPATH/mail
```

I have copy/pasted your commands assuming that they work.  The difference is everything is handled with only one redirection, hoping that this would avoid any buffering issue that could influence the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks Fred.I'll try it out although as I said this doesn't seem to occur everytime , so I don't know if I can properly test it.

Comment: Output that is sometimes garbled, and sometimes not, seems just like the kind of problem this could potentially help with, but this is a shot in the dark, of course, so I cannot positively state that it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes it might not help at all, but still I appreciate your help.

Comment: @VeselinIvanov Did you find the reason why it is happening? I am also facing similar issue with one of my script.